# Delete RealmObject displayed in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I wanna display some RealmObjects(ideas) from a RealmList (ideaList) to a Recyclerview. Sounds easy. But when i try to delete an Object, it's though there when i do a Query(for getting all ideas from a specific user)

Code examples:

query:

```
public RealmList<Idea> getIdeaListFromRealm(Context ctx) {
    realm = Realm.getInstance(ctx);
    RealmQuery<Idea> ideaQuery = realm.where(Idea.class);
    RealmResults<Idea> ideaQueryResults = ideaQuery.equalTo("owner.id",""+LoginFragment.loggedOwner.getId()).findAll();
    RealmList<Idea> ideaList = new RealmList<>();
    ideaList.addAll(ideaQueryResults);
    return ideaList;
}
```

delete(onClick)
:

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            realm.beginTransaction();
            ideaList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            realm.commitTransaction();
            fragmentStateHandler.replaceFrag(Frag.ARCHIVEFRAGMENT);
        }
    });
```

I think i did not delete it properly. There can be no other reason, because it's still there in the query after deleting.

What am i doing wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *removing* the object just from the `RealmList`, which isn't persisted at all.

You've to *delete* the object either from the results or just directly going over the object instance. e.g.

```
 realm.beginTransaction();

 ideaQueryResults.remove(position);

 // alternatively:

 Idea idea = ideaQueryResults.get(position);
 idea.removeFromRealm();

 realm.commitTransaction();

 // from the docs: it will always be more efficient to
 // use the more specific change events if you can.
 // Rely on notifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort.
 notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Comment: I think you should commit before you notify the dataset.